# Deploying a simple contract using liquidity

Tags: liquidity, contract

Contract (simple.liq):

```
[%%version 1.0]

type storage = int

let%init storage = 0

let%entry main (parameter : int) storage =
  ( [], storage + parameter )
```

Deployment command:

```
liquidity --tezos-node http://alphanet-node.tzscan.io:80 --private-key <key> --protocol alphanet simple.liq --deploy
```

After I run this command I get the following error that I cannot make sense of:

```
Response Error:
in /chains/main/blocks/head/helpers/preapply/operations
- branch: proto.003-PsddFKi3.implicit.empty_implicit_contract
```

It seems that the node thinks that our implicit contract is empty.

Comment: Looks like it's trying to use a mainnet node:

    proto.003-PsddFKi3

This refers to the proto 003 protocol that the mainnet runs, not the protocol for alphanet (which is `PsddFKi32cMJ2qPjf43Qv5GDWLDPZb3T3bF6fLKiF5HtvHNU7aP`)

Comment: @StephenAndrews perhaps this is a valid answer ?

Comment: @StephenAndrews I use the `--protocol alphanet` option, if that does not result in using the alphanet, then how should I do that?

Comment: I don't know, I don't use liquidity - I'm just making an observation that the error being reported is from the mainnet protocol. @Ezy I don't think it's a valid answer, just a comment/observation - someone with experience with Liquidity should be able to answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using a private key which do not correspond to any account on the alphanet.
It works with

```
liquidity --tezos-node http://alphanet-node.tzscan.io:80 --private-key edsk2j7Ka5nRzh2QkGCtcD1dFLbHYvYw7XAafWL3YEAQQ3Zd61NiqS --protocol alphanet simple.liq --deploy
```

```
Main contract Simple
New contract KT18bLbXyH5yMY9ShDfCwtiXegWHMTa4aS8H deployed in operation opENiYZ3xMTDu1hVdLi7kSU3cybucZrDnAUXznMgCr2twecAu9S
```

You can also deploy on the alphanet with http://www.liquidity-lang.org/edit/ which allows you to see the balance on your account and interact with deployed smart contract.

Comment: Thank you, this sounds like it is indeed the problem. Since I saw your answer I have been trying to get tez on my account, but I run into this problem: https://tezos.stackexchange.com/questions/917/activating-an-account-on-alphanet-using-public-node